# Escape backquote in a double-quoted string in shell

Tags: shell, quotes, quoting, backticks

For the command: /usr/bin/sh -c "ls 1`" (a backquote after 1).

How to make it run successfully? Adding a backslash before "`" does not work. 
` is a special char as we know, and I tried surrounding it with single quote too (/usr/bin/sh -c "ls 1'`'"), but that doesn't work either.

The error always are:

```
% /usr/bin/sh -c "ls 1\`"
Unmatched `
```

Comment: Do you have a single backtick ? Is `1\`` a filename ?

Comment: Yes, actually I can create one file named "1`" by issuing command "touch 1`", but shell just cannot parse it inside double quotes

Answer (score 73):

You need to escape the backtick, but also escape the backslash:

```
$ touch 1\`
$ /bin/sh -c "ls 1\\\`"
1`
```

The reason you have to escape it "twice" is because you're entering this command in an environment (such as a shell script) that interprets the double-quoted string once.  It then gets interpreted again by the subshell.

You could also avoid the double-quotes, and thus avoid the first interpretation:

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'ls 1\`'
1`
```

Another way is to store the filename in a variable, and use that value:

```
$ export F='1`'
$ printenv F
1`
$ /bin/sh -c 'ls $F'  # note that /bin/sh interprets $F, not my current shell
1`
```

And finally, what you tried will work on some shells (I'm using bash, as for the above examples), just apparently not with your shell:

```
$ /bin/sh -c "ls 1'\`'"
1`
$ csh  # enter csh, the next line is executed in that environment
% /bin/sh -c "ls 1'\`'"
Unmatched `.
```

I strongly suggest you avoid such filenames in the [first place](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).

Comment: +1 `what you tried will work on some shells just apparently not with your shell:` - The git-bash v4.4.23 shell in Windows is one example of this. You can't even run this simple command directly in the terminal: `export x="ab\`cd"`

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes instead:

```
/usr/bin/sh -c 'ls 1\`'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/sh -c "ls '1\`'"
```