# Escape backtick in Go (string used in exec.Command)

Tags: go

Given this code, I can't figure out how to escape the backtick.

```
var (
    MY_STRING = "something`something"
)
cmd := fmt.Sprintf("MY_ENV=%q;", MY_STRING)
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).CombinedOutput()
// results in MY_ENV="something`something" ie unfinished input
```

I've tried the below but it results in "unknown escape sequence". It does work in the shell obviously.  I've also tried to combine strings and raw string literals but with no success.  How can I escape the backtick please?

```
var (
    MY_STRING = "something\`something"
)
```

Comment: Please clearly indicate your error - that error isn't coming from Go itself, which  doesn't care about backticks in strings (https://play.golang.org/p/HuxBqxCth1p) so most likely it's coming from your shell.

Comment: exit status 1: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Comment: Just a note to recommend considering `$(my command)` instead of `\`my command\``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'` to escape `` ` `` in Bourne shells. And no need to quote the string.

```golang
MY_STRING := "something'`'something"
cmd := fmt.Sprintf("MY_ENV=%s;", MY_STRING)
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).CombinedOutput()
```

Comment: “*no need to quote the string*” - `%q` doesn’t just add double quotes, it also adds escape sequences where necessary.

Comment: True but it doesn't escape the string in a way that is useful in a Bourne shell.

Comment: @rix https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught

Answer (score 2):

The backtick doesn’t need escaping for Go to leave it in the string ([*ref*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21198980/1813169)).

However, bash will treat backticks outside of a string as [subshell syntax](https://serverfault.com/q/286204/147388). The easiest way to escape a backtick in bash is to include it in a [single-quoted string](https://serverfault.com/q/286204/147388):

```
var MY_STRING = "'something`something'"
```

But since you’re using `%q` in your format string, this won’t behave as expected.

Instead, you can use the solution posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1824160/1813169). Bash requires double escaping the backtick (`` \\\` ``) inside double quotes. There’s a full explanation for why this is necessary in that linked question. Since Go also uses `\` as an escape character, you’ll need to double up each one:

```
var MY_STRING = "something\\\\\\`something"
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  It outputs `MY_ENV="something\\`something"` and the shell error is `exit status 1: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'`

Comment: @MTCoster That will still not work because they quote the string below (`%q`), so it will end up being `"'something\`something'"`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `//go:embed foo.sh` embed external shell file to your code. like this:

```
    //go:embed yourshell.sh
    var yourshell string
```

put the shell file in the same folder of your code.
details of go embed : https://pkg.go.dev/embed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).