# MySql query fails when the shell variable contains ampersand

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a table variable in shell-script which contains '&'. When I try to update the table in shell script the query fails.

I have tried several options to embrace the table name with single quotes, double quotes, back quote '`' (back quote considers the statement in it as a command to shell)

Also tried setting below options:
set define on
set escape on

```
#!/bin/bash

Table='City_&_District'
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
update $Table set Actual='$Actual', Normal='$Normal', Dep_Per='$Dep', Cat='$Cat' where Date='$Date';
EOF
```

If I Input Table name as: 'City' the query succeeds 
If I Input Table name as: 'City_&_District' the query Fails

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '&_District set Actual='0.4', Normal='0.1',
>   Dep_Per='340%', Cat='LE' where Date='' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: If your table name contains special characters, you should quote it with backticks. ``update `$Table` ...``

Comment: backtick is not working in this case

Comment: As we see from the accepted answer they do work. How to pass them in the shell command - is another question: [escape-backquote-in-a-double-quoted-string-in-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824160/escape-backquote-in-a-double-quoted-string-in-shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using backslashes with backticks as backticks are considered Command Substitution in shell and they are evaluated in double quoted strings.

You need to escape the backticks

"\`City_&_District\`"

Comment: Yes I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Use can use ` around the table name (not ' or ")

Answer (score 0):

Adding backslash before backtick works in table variable